# libcocos2dx resource error: resource directory does not exist

Tags: android, eclipse, box2d, cocos2d-x-3.0

Yesterday I tried to add Box2D to my cocos2dx project. One error appeared and I haven't been able to solve it. The error:

```
[2015-03-06 10:41:41 - libcocos2dx] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\devAndroid\cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\SuperCars\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android\java\res' does not exist
```

The point is that the package explorer itself only shows a red exclamation in the project folder... Sometimes the libcocos2dx folder also shows a red X.
I've tried everything I found on the net:

- Clean Project
- Re-create the project
- I've checked my Android.mk file hundreds of times...

Currently, the **Android.mk** content is the above

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/RaceScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Box2D

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static    

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
$(call import-module,audio/android)
$(call import-module,Box2D)
```

I've read in another Stackoverflow post that a similar error can manifest when upgrading SDK Tools. I haven't done it.

The only thing I did is trying to add Box2D module.

Any help will be great. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting the same error. I just created a res empty folder that was missing, and the error was gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed it by re-creating the project. I don't still know why the first time I did this it didn't work.

[Here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/project-throws-error-after-compiling-but-it-is-not-showed/20303) is the official Cocos2d-x forum post I opened, where I posted the "solution".

Hope it helps someone.